# Passing an instantiated object or initializing a class variable through a class method causes error in running server ZeroRPC

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb, zerorpc

So I have this setup for my back-end, Python handling data-mining and communicates with the database (MongoDB through PyMongo), and Node.js/Restify invoking the Python methods through ZeroRPC.

I have the following classes with functions as follows:

- `Importer` - imports, transforms, and cleans the data from the csv to json data.
- `Database` - the database object, contains the MongoClient and handles the inserting of the imported data from `Importer`.
- `Analytics` - the object that contains the data mining methods; the one to be passed to the `zerorpc.Server`. Needs to be passed an instance or the `Database` class instead to have access to the database.

So here's how my `app.py` looks like.

```
import os
import zerorpc

from scripts.database import Database
from scripts.importer import Importer
from scripts.analytics import Analytics

from utils.timer import time_function

ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    importer = Importer()

    db = Database(data=importer.data)

    services = Analytics(db)

    server = zerorpc.Server(services)
    server.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:1234")
    server.run()
```

Yet it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Projects/Dashboards/app/app.py", line 28, in <module>
    server = zerorpc.Server(Analytics())
  File "D:\Projects\Dashboards\env\lib\site-packages\zerorpc\core.py", line 292, in __init__
    pool_size, heartbeat)
  File "D:\Projects\Dashboards\env\lib\site-packages\zerorpc\core.py", line 72, in __init__
    self._methods[k] = rep(functor)
  File "D:\Projects\Dashboards\env\lib\site-packages\zerorpc\decorators.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.__name__ = functor.__name__
  File "D:\Projects\Dashboards\env\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 262, in __getattr__
    name, full_name, full_name))
AttributeError: Collection has no attribute '__name__'. To access the sales.__name__ collection, use database['sales.__name__'].

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**So at this point I realized, "maybe because I passed an instance of the object and not the object itself."**

So I transformed my `Analytics` into this:

```
from bson.son import SON
import datetime

class Analytics(object):
    # def __init__(self, database):
    #     self.db = database.db
    #     self.sales = database.tb_sales

    @classmethod
    def connect_db(cls, database):
        cls.db = database.db
        cls.sales = database.tb_sales

    ...other methods here...
```

Where the class method `connect_db` was once the `__init__` of `Analytics`. And thus my `app.py` is changed to:

```
import os
import zerorpc

from scripts.database import Database
from scripts.importer import Importer
from scripts.analytics import Analytics

from utils.timer import time_function

ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    importer = Importer()

    db = Database(data=importer.data)

    Analytics.connect_db(database=db)

    server = zerorpc.Server(Analytics())
    server.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:1234")
    server.run()
```

**But still it shows THE SAME ERROR.**

Why is that? Any ideas?
Somehow I think it has something to do of `zerorpc`'s nature of getting the `__name__` of functions so that it can be invoked by the client? Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

zerorpc.Server does expect a class instance. By default it tries to guess the service name via the `instance.__name__` attribute which is not available in your case.

You can set the name yourself like so:

```
server = zerorpc.Server(services, name="mysuperservice")
```